# How do I migrate Mongo collections into Elasticsearch using Mongolastic?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to transfer data from Mongo to Elasticsearch using Mongolastic.

My simple config like so:

```
misc:
    dindex:
        name: my_db
    ctype:
        name: collection1
mongo:
    host: localhost
    port: 27017
elastic:
    host: localhost
    port: 9300
```

The config says that Mongolastic will transfer the collection1 from my_db on Mongo to Elasticsearch by create new index name my_db.
That means I will got only collection1 in Elasticsearch.

So my question is there are ways to transfer all collections from my_db to Elasticsearch just one hit?

Comment: you can do your aim @Disuan, for the mongodb perspective, index is database and type is collection. so after running this conf on mongolastic, all your mongodb data should be migrated to the my_db type of the collection1 index on your elasticsearch node. you can only migrate a collection one by one. If you want you can open an issue on the mongolastic page https://github.com/ozlerhakan/mongolastic for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you @Hakan, That is the only way I got.